# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 426 in React app newsapi call

Tags: reactjs, github

I have a React app hosted on GitHub that makes a call out to the newsapi.org API.  Locally the app is working fine, but in gh-pages URL in some browsers i.e. chrome I am getting the following error which is not allowing the newsapi information to load:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
GET https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=7a4e481d736140efae783b1bfd607fbe 426
createError.js:16 
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 426
    at e.exports (createError.js:16)
    at e.exports (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.p.onreadystatechange (xhr.js:61)
```

The repo is at https://github.com/MarkMGill/Newscast, and gh-pages URL is https://markmgill.github.io/Newscast/.  I've tried googling 426, but there isn't a lot of useful info I can find.  Appreciate anyone who may know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just researched some more and found new information saying newsapi.org has changed its free service to only allow API calls locally.  This explains why my app in gh-pages is no longer loading API info.